# Prevent minecraft (Java) from downloading log4j 2.14.1

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, minecraft

I've been looking into hardening my Windows machine against the recent log4j vulnerabilities (CVE-2021-44228, CVE-2021-45046, CVE-2021-45105). Fortuanetly, the only java application I have is minecraft.

On the official minecraft website, the developer claims that upgrading to v1.18.1 will fix the problem. I did that, but found that vulnerable versions of log4j (2.14.1) were still present at `%APPDATA%/.minecraft/libraries` and still contain `JndiLookup.class`. So it seems to me that the only thing that was the developers did was to set the `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` system property. This is, according to Apache, NOT sufficient (see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

I've tried:

- updating log4j myself by manually placing the 2.17.0 version of log4j in `%APPDATA%/.minecraft/libraries`.
- manually deleting `JndiLookup.class` from the 2.14.1-jar
- overwriting the 2.14.1 version with 2.17.0

But each time, after launching the game, the old versions were back. It seems the game is ensuring validity and integrity of their third-party libraries. Normally, I would see this as a good thing, but in this case it's quite the opposite.

Has anybody managed to launch minecraft with safe versions of 2.17.0? Any tips on how to trick

Comment: Really. This should be discussed with the Minecraft developer(s).

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to run MinecraftForge instead ([Download](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/)). They have addressed the Log4j security vulnerability by bumping to version 2.15:
https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/commit/14e152579b8cbdb5f6c2e9ba089bf7971a1a727a